# How do I speed up a call to top in a shell script using zsh?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

I have a script that I run inside an oh-my-zsh prompt that shows this information:

```
(68% disk used) (1.48[16] cores @ 8.7%) (16G used / 16G) 100%
```

It seems like it's calling `top` multiple times and thus it takes a LONG time (several seconds - long enough to be annoying) to display after each carriage return and therefore calling this script for the oh-my-zsh prompt. Is there any way to speed this up? When I call `top`, I'm using options that only output one page of top's output - a "snapshot" of top's information that I use to display the load average, the percentage of "on time" of the processor, and the amount of RAM I'm currently using. I know for a fact that calling `top -l 1 -s 0` does not take longer than even a quarter of a second, so my script must be calling it multiple times unless I'm missing something else entirely... the `sysctl hw` command is also quite fast, as is `pmset -g batt` and `df -h`. Anyways, here's the script:

```
#!/bin/zsh

toplist=(top -l 1 -s 0)
sysctllist=(sysctl hw)
pmsetlist=(pmset -g batt)
storagelist=(df -h)

availablestorage=$($storagelist | grep "/dev/disk1s2" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/Gi//')
availablestorage=$((availablestorage * 1.073741824))
usedstorage=$($storagelist | grep "/" | awk '{print $3}' | grep "Gi" | sed 's/Gi//' | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }')
usedstorage=$((usedstorage * 1.073741824))
storagepercentused=$((100 * (usedstorage / availablestorage)))
storagepercentusedrounded=$( echo "($storagepercentused)/1" | bc)

loadavg=$($toplist | grep 'Load Avg' | awk '{print $3, $4, $5}' | tr -d , | awk '{print $2}')
ncpu=$($sysctllist | grep ".ncpu" | grep -o -E '[1-9]+')
percentidle=$($toplist | grep 'CPU usage:' | awk '{print $3, $5, $7}' | tr -d , | tr -d % | awk '{print $3}')
memoryfree=$($toplist | grep 'PhysMem' | awk '{print $2}')
totalmemory=$($sysctllist | grep .memsize | grep -oE '[1-9]+')
batterypercent=""$($pmsetlist | grep "%" | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d \;)"%"
power=""
if ($pmsetlist | grep "Battery Power") >> /dev/null then
    power=""
elif ($pmsetlist | grep "AC Power") >> /dev/null then
    power=""
fi

echo "($storagepercentusedrounded%% disk used) ("$loadavg"["$ncpu"] cores @ "$(printf '%.*f\n' 1 $((100 - $percentidle)))"%%) ("$memoryfree" used / "$(($totalmemory / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))"G)" %F{white}$batterypercent $power
```

Comment: This is a ridiculous number of commands to run every single time you want to print a shell prompt. You don't need `df -h | grep | awk | sed` -- you can do the whole thing with just `df -h | awk` with a smarter awk expression. And if you're going to be reusing the output of `top`, **store the results and reuse them**, don't run it over and over.

Comment: That is, `toplist=( top -l 1 -s 0 )` is storing the top command line and running a new copy of that command every time you use it; it's not storing top's output. If you want to store top's output, that's `topout=$(top -l 1 -s 0)`, and then use `<<<"$topout"`

Comment: But _really_, cut down all the `grep | awk | tr | awk`. You never need more than one awk, and it can do everything grep and tr can do.

Comment: `df -h` can be asked to only print out information about one filesystem. That might be faster.

Comment: I'd also think about writing single executable that does all this work. Use a language that has a high-level library like Python's psutils and it won't be all that much trouble. Make it a service that can run in the background and then you don't even pay the cost to start new copies over and over. (A lot of the commands are also just reading procfs under the hood; starting a new executable to read a procfs file when you could just read that file yourself is silly).

Comment: Could you get the values of $ncpu and $totalmemory once, in your .zshrc, and pass them to this prompt as environment variables? That would mean that your prompt would not update the number of CPUs and total memory until your terminal is closed and re-opened, but that seems like it never happens without at least a restart.

Comment: BTW, `foo | grep -q bar` is faster than `foo | grep bar >/dev/null` because if `grep` _knows_ its stdout isn't required, it can exit the moment it sees a match instead of needing to read through the rest of `foo`'s output. But even then, in a lot of cases `[[ $string =~ regex ]]` is faster than `<<<"$string" grep -q regex`, and of course both are faster than `generate_a_string | grep -q regex`.

Comment: Lol, I knew there was a way to store the results and reuse them, I didn't know it was `<<<"$toplist"` - this alone cut the time at least in half. Using `grep -q` helped as well. My remaining work that needs to be done is using awk alone... @CharlesDuffy could you give me an example? I'm also seriously considering using python instead.

Comment: `[[ $pmsetlist =~ "Battery Power" ]]` was indeed faster as well

Comment: So, for example, to replace `grep foo | awk '{print $3}'`, you'd use `awk '/foo/ { print $3 }'`. To make awk also replace strings you might use `gsub`, but awk is a whole general-purpose scripting language, so I can't really summarize it in a comment.

Comment: Maybe... `availablestorage=$(<<<"$storage_out" awk -v drive="/dev/disk1s2" '$1 == drive { gsub("Gi", ""); print($2 * 1.073741824); }')` is a good example of how I'd rewrite your first pipeline (and the command after it) to be nothing but awk, assuming you previously ran `storage_out=$(df -h)` (or, better, `storage_out=$(df -h /dev/disk1s2)`).

Comment: BTW, you can also tell awk to round your numbers for you by using `printf` in it with a format string that specifies the number of digits you want. There's no reason for `storagepercentusedrounded` to be more than one awk command, for that matter; don't need to run awk twice to get two different numbers and divide them when you can have one copy of awk collect both numbers and do the math itself.

Comment: That said, using `-h` is probably a bad idea in the first place when you want your numbers to be right. What if `df` decides it wants to measure output for one entry in `Tb` and the other in `Mb`? Much more reliable if you leave human-readable mode turned off so the numbers use the same units everywhere.

Comment: Awesome advice! I decided to use a different route - df already tells me how much space I've used, and to match the right disk I changed the awk to look for /System/Volumes/Data. I did this:  `storagepercentused=$(<<<"$storageout" | awk -v drive="/System/Volumes/Data" '$9 == drive {print $5}')
`

Comment: From what I see, you are running `top` only twice in your script, but you run plenty of other commands unnecessarily - for instance, the 3 processes `grep...|awk...|sed...` can be substituted by a single awk process. It is OK if you hack down the first version of your script without thinking of performance - making optimisations to early is usually a bad idea. But now that you see that it's to slow, find which parts take most time, and optimize those.

Comment: Turns out the main thing that takes so long, even with Python and psutil, is the CPU percentage - it requires at least like half a second if not a second or two to average the use of the processor. The getloadavg is automatically stored every 5 seconds and averages over 1 minute, 5 minutes, and 15 minutes, and is practically instant. As soon as I took out the top command and used Python & psutil and shutil, everything ran instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the biggest problem was the top command itself. It requires at least a second or two to average the processor percentage. So, when I switched to Python, I used psutil to get the load averages on the processor - which are stored automatically every 5 seconds and averages over 1 minute, 5 minutes, and 15 minutes. It's practically instant. Once I took out top, and used python's psutil, shutil, and os libraries, everything works swimmingly.

```
#!/Users/jacobjackson/repos/python_class/venv/bin/python3

import psutil
import shutil
import os

vm = psutil.virtual_memory()

memory_used = f"{round((vm.used / vm.total)*100)}%%"

du = shutil.disk_usage("/")

disk_percent = f"{round((du.used / du.total)*100)}%%"

load1, load5, load15 = psutil.getloadavg()

cpu_usage = f"{round(load5/os.cpu_count()*100)}%%"

battery_status = psutil.sensors_battery()
battery_percent = f"{battery_status.percent}%%"
ac_power = battery_status.power_plugged

if ac_power == True:
    power=""
else:
    power=""

print(f"{disk_percent} disk | {cpu_usage} cpu | {memory_used} mem | {battery_percent} {power}")
```